# view page source does not show page in nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I shifted my project from CRA to nextjs because of SEO. On Sever side rendering, the client gets a complete HTML page as a response but in my case when i view page source of my landing page then i just see `<div id="__next"><div></div></div>`.  On every pages, the page source shows the same.

Here is my code

pages/index.js

```
const IndexPage = () => {
  return (
    <Layout title="Home">
      <Home />
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default IndexPage;
```

_app.js

```
class MyApp extends App {
  render() {
    const { Component, pageProps, apolloClient } = this.props;
    return (
        <ApolloProvider client={apolloClient}>
            <UserProvider>
              <RoleBasedComponent comp={Component} {...pageProps} />
            </UserProvider>
        </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }
}

export default withApollo(MyApp, {
  ssr: false,
});
```

Is there something i did to violate the concept of server side rendering? Can anyone help me to understand why the HTML response is not viewable when looking at the view page source? I am totally confused and I afraid if google bot cannot index the page for SEO.

UPDATE

UserContext.js

```
const UserContext = createContext();

// Use this wherever current user data is required eg const {currentUser, loading} = useContext(UserContext)
const UserProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const token = cookies.getSession();
  return (
    <Query
      query={GET_CURRENT_USER}
      variables={{
        input: {
          token,
        },
      }}
    >
      {({ data, refetch, loading }) => {
        const currentUser = get(data, 'currentUser.data');

        if (loading) return <div />;

        return (
          <UserContext.Provider
            value={{ currentUser, loading, refetchUser: refetch }}
          >
            {children}
          </UserContext.Provider>
        );
      }}
    </Query>
  );
};
```

Comment: because `ssr: false` or no component rendered when no user role?

Comment: If there is fetching/conditional rendering done in any of those providers? If so you need to be able to do that fetching on the server.

Comment: condition is used on UserProvider because i need to know about current user in every pages.

Comment: @tenor528 sorry i did not understand "If so you need to be able to do that fetching on the server". Can you help me understand this, please?

Comment: I was just saying that if there is logic related to that UserProvider that doesn't render the page until the user is found, you may need logic to make sure the user can be found when the code is executed on the server as well as the client. This may mean calling your endpoint on the server, or it may be as simple as the other suggestions of turning ssr mode on (which will allow server-side fetching).

Answer (score 0):

When rendering the component ``MyApp` you're passing:

```
{export default withApollo(MyApp, {
  ssr: false, // Should be true
});}
```

I would give a read to this page - https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/performance/server-side-rendering/

It can probably help.

Comment: i turned ssr to true but still I could not see the source code.

Answer (score 0):

u can use this from documentation ... https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document (Customizing renderPage)

and try to include strategy='beforeInteractive' inside Scripts.
In my case i receive some props from each article (or each page) That is why i used extra tags. Be careful about your layout .Try to make layout which will dynamically receive meta tags or link tags which u will include inside metagas

Here is code example

```html
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';
import Script from 'next/script';
import React from 'react';

class CustomDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    let pageProps = null;
    const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;
    ctx.renderPage = () =>
      originalRenderPage({
        enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => {
          pageProps = props.pageProps;
          return <App {...props} />
        },
        enhanceComponent: (Component) => Component,
      })
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
    return { ...initialProps, pageProps }
  }

  render() {
    const { pageProps } = this.props;

    let {
      title = "Your page title",
      description = " Your description",
      keywords = "Your keywordss",
      extraTags=[],
    } = (typeof pageProps === 'object' && typeof pageProps.head === 'object') ? pageProps.head : {};

    return (
      <Html>
        <Head >
          <title>{title}</title>
          <meta name="description" content={description} />
          <meta name="keywords" content={keywords} />
         
       
          {extraTags.map((tag, i) => {
            let { attr, name, textContent } = tag;
            if (name === 'link') {
              return <link key={i} {...attr} />
            } else if (name === 'script') {
              let { type, data } = typeof textContent === 'object' ? textContent : {};
              if (type === 'object') {
                return <Script key={i} {...attr} strategy='beforeInteractive' >{JSON.stringify(data)}</Script>
              } else if (type === 'string') {
                return <Script key={i} {...attr} strategy='beforeInteractive' >{data}</Script>
              } {
                return <React.Fragment key={i}></React.Fragment>
              }
            } else {
              return <React.Fragment key={i}></React.Fragment>
            }
          })}
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default CustomDocument;
```