# links are not visible in page source in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to include links within my top menu component in page source code but I haven't been successful yet. This is the piece of code I'm working on:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Link from "next/link";

import Styles from "./MegaMenuSublist.module.css";

const MegaMenuSublist = (props) => {

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      {props.mainCategory == "digital" && (
        <div className={Styles.CategoryOptionsList}>
          <div className={Styles.CategorySubListHeadline}>

            {/* <a href="#"> */}
            <a href="/main-category/digital/">

              <svg
                className={Styles.SubListHeadlineChevLeft}
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                fill="none"
                viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                stroke="currentColor"
              >
                <path
                  strokeLinecap="round"
                  strokeLinejoin="round"
                  strokeWidth={2}
                  d="M15 19l-7-7 7-7"
                />
              </svg>
              هall cat

            </a>
            {/* */}
          </div>
          <ul>
            <li className={Styles.SubListTitle}>
                <a href='/category/mobile-accessories/'>
                  mobile-accessories
                </a>
            </li>
            <li className={Styles.SubListItem}>
              <a href='/category/cell-phone-pouch-cover/'>
                cell-phone-pouch-cover
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className={Styles.SubListItem}>
              <a href='/category/power-bank/'>
                power-bank
              </a>
            </li>
            <li className={Styles.SubListItem}>
              <a href='/category/cell-phone-holder/'>
                cell-phone-holder
              </a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
```

I want to see for example `/main-category/digital/` in page source to be crawled by google robot.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You import Link from Next but never use it. Using it would probably fix your issue

Comment: And I guess you have to make sure you use SSR or SSG

Comment: I used it but it didn't work

Comment: Are you using SSR or SSG?

Comment: I'm using SSR. and here I want to share my links in whole site

Comment: Check this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62064804/view-page-source-does-not-show-page-in-nextjs/74078879#74078879 (which answered by me)

Answer (score 0):

Links in NextJS should be wrapped in a Link component

```
<Link href="/main-category/digital/">
  <a>

    <svg
      className={Styles.SubListHeadlineChevLeft}
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      fill="none"
      viewBox="0 0 24 24"
      stroke="currentColor"
    >
      <path
        strokeLinecap="round"
        strokeLinejoin="round"
        strokeWidth={2}
        d="M15 19l-7-7 7-7"
      />
    </svg>
    هall cat

  </a>
</Link>
```